# Python requests 2.31.0 with urllib3 >= version 2 not automatically decompressing gzip responses

Tags: python-requests, gzip, urllib3, python-requests-json

Been relying on requests' ability to auto-decompress responses for a long time now, as per https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/faq/#encoded-data

However, I'm having a new problem in that it seems that when urllib3 v2 or greater is installed, it's causing gzip server responses to not be automatically decompressed? Currently testing with the latest urllib3 -- v2.0.4

Here are the server response headers:

```
{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Length': '438882', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Thu, 28 May 2020 13:58:44 GMT', 'Server': 'Werkzeug/0.16.1 Python/3.7.4', 'Set-Cookie': '00JjTgL6zvaENlsRPoILCbSuUjTiiv7B9hLvy41-QF=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/, session=eyJvaWRjX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iOiJ6QUZ0ZF9TNml5M0NqNnR3TWYyWjR2YXZKME5jM05vdyJ9.Xs_DlA.ijqNu8eoHFmkUmgn1-2HchDk-P0; HttpOnly; Path=/', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Cookie'}
```

However, `response.json()` blows up.

If I do `json.loads(zlib.decompress(response.content, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS))` -- I successfully load the json into python.

Pinning to 'urllib3<2', and `response.json()` works again -- data is automatically decompressed and loaded into python.

The server response is from a stored vcrpy object, so it identical in either case. The only difference is the urllib3 version.

Did something change with expected usage for urllib3 v2?

Comment: In your Question, can you include the exact urllib version, and any configuration you have for PoolManager?

Comment: Updated question with urllib3 version -- there's no PoolManager configuration anywhere in my setup